# Monkey patch a function in a module for unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, monkeypatching

I have the following method in a module that calls another method imported from another module:

```
def imported_function():
    do_unnecessary_things_for_unittest()
```

The actual method that needs to be tested, imports and uses the above function:

```
from somewhere import imported_function

def function_to_be_tested():
    imported_function()
    do_something_more()
    return 42
```

The inner calls and related calculations inside **imported_function** are not important and they are not what I want to test so I just want to skip them while testing the actual function **function_to_be_tested**.

Thus, I tried to monkey patch the module named **somewhere** inside the test method but no luck.

```
def test_function_to_be_tested(self):
    import somewhere
    somewhere.__dict__['imported_function'] = lambda : True
```

The question is, how can I monkey patch a method of a module while testing so that it will not be called during the test phase?

Comment: Not directly answering your questions, but I suggest using a mocking library, such as `mocktest`: http://gfxmonk.net/dist/doc/mocktest/doc/ Apart from just mocking objects and functions, this library also allows you to define expectations on function calls. For example, you can define that `function_to_be_tested` must be called once with no arguments. You can also define what value should the function return. If the expectations are not met, the test will fail. This adds extra safety, since you know that the function has actually been called during the test as you intended.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think better to use [Mock Library](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock/)

So you can do something like:

```
from somewhere import imported_function

@patch(imported_function)
def test_function_to_be_tested(self, imported_function):
    imported_function.return_value = True
    #Your test
```

I think for unit tests it's better than monkey patch.

Comment: I had to do `@patch('imported_function')` to make it works.

Answer (score 8):

Say you have the following files:

**somewhere.py**

```
def imported_function():
    return False
```

**testme.py**

```
from somewhere import imported_function

def function_to_be_tested():
    return imported_function()
```

A call to `testme.function_to_be_tested()` would return `False`.

---

Now, the trick is to import `somewhere` *before* `testme`:

```
import somewhere
somewhere.__dict__['imported_function'] = lambda : True

import testme
def test_function_to_be_tested():
    print testme.function_to_be_tested()

test_function_to_be_tested()
```

**Output:**

> True

---

Or, reload the `testme` module

```
import testme

def test_function_to_be_tested():
    print testme.function_to_be_tested()
    import somewhere
    somewhere.__dict__['imported_function'] = lambda : True
    print testme.function_to_be_tested()
    reload(testme)
    print testme.function_to_be_tested()

test_function_to_be_tested()
```

**Output:**

> False
>   False
>   True